# Use C++11 condition_varible to make 3 threads print 1-100 in turns. But the dead lock confuses me

Tags: multithreading, c++11, synchronous, condition-variable

I want to write a program use 3 threads to print 1-100 in turns using C++11 condition_variable, but dead lock confused me, here are my code:

the tmp.cpp is:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>


std::condition_variable cv12;
std::condition_variable cv23;
std::condition_variable cv31;

std::mutex mtx;

void Print(int i) {
  while (i <= 100) {
    if (i % 3 == 1) {
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        cv31.wait(l);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }

      cv12.notify_all();
    } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        cv12.wait(l);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }

      cv23.notify_all();
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        cv23.wait(l);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }

      cv31.notify_all();
    }
    i += 3;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(Print, 1);
  std::thread t2(Print, 2);
  std::thread t3(Print, 3);

  cv31.notify_all();

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();

  return 0;
}
```

the run command is:

```bash
$ g++ -g -o tmp tmp.cpp  && ./tmp
```

But the output sometimes could just and stops.

```bash
╰─$ ./tmp                
1
2
```

When I ask GPT or Claud, they give me no advice, that imply my code may correct, when I use gdb to debug for the deadlock, but this program always run correctly in gdb, which dead lock never occurs.

I refer to the ways of [condition varible wait usage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), may should add a Predicate, but I don't want to write more global varible to handle this, and I find the Predicate is optional, so I don't know where is the bug in my code?

Comment: My guess would be, the second thread manages to start and call `cv23.notify_all()` before the third thread gets to `cv23.wait(l)`. So it misses the wake-up, and ends up waiting forever. This is why condition variable is meant to protect some condition (hence the name) - the thread should check the condition and not even wait if that condition is already true.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I insert some time elapsed code before the cv12.notify_all(); just like this: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));` so the dead lock never happen. I think you are right, and the meaning of condition varible reminds me have to set some other flag to protect this condition.

Comment: @yorkking never use sleeps to correct such a thing. Much better is to correctly design your algorithm.

Comment: I just use the sleeps to verify the above explanation. Yeah, you are right, I add a Predicate  to correct my program and fix the bug.
The code would be:
```C++

Answer (score 0):

You may wait if the thread id is not the right one:

```
std::condition_variable cv;

std::mutex mtx;

void Print(int i) {
  static volatile int n = 1; // shared variable

  while (n <= 100) {
    { // new block to release the lock at the end of each turn
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
      // wait if it is not your turn and n<=100
      while (n%3!=i%3 && n<=100) cv.wait(l);
      if (n<=100) {
        std::cout << i << ',' << n << std::endl;
        n++;
      }
      cv.notify_all();
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
1,4
2,5
3,6
1,7
2,8
3,9
1,10
2,11
...
```

Comment: Thx, you are right. Finally, we have to use another shared variable(which in your code is n) to determine which thread is in turn to print.